# In RDF how do I convert a literal string value to an object using SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, rdf

Given I have `:datatypeproperty_a` and `:objectproperty_a` and the following triple:

```
?a :datatypeproperty_a ?b .
```

How do I construct

```
?a :objectproperty_a ?x . 
?x rdfs:label ?b .
```

(?x is a new resource)

Comment: The first is not a triple but a triple pattern. And it depends on how you want to define the URI of `?x` which also depends on what kind of literal `?b` is. If you know that you can generate URIs (resp. IRIs) with https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-iri

Answer (score 3):

I suppose that ?b is a string.

Then :

```
CONSTRUCT {
?a :objectproperty_a _:x . 
_:x rdfs:label ?b . 
}
WHERE {
?a :datatypeproperty_a ?b .
}
```

will do what you want adding a blank node as new resource (i.e. a resource with no declared URI).

You must be more specific if you want to construct a URI for the added resource (there are several ways to do that).